# Is the object "this" points to the same as a const object?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants, const-correctness, this-pointer

This question has to to do with overloading the assignment operator in c++. Take a look at the following code. It shows the function definition given by my book to overload the assignment operator.

```
const cAssignmentOprOverload& cAssignmentOprOverload::operator=(
    const cAssignmentOprOverload& otherList) {
  if (this != &otherList)  // avoid self-assignment; Line 1
  {
    delete[] list;                    // Line 2
    maxSize = otherList.maxSize;      // Line 3
    length = otherList.length;        // Line 4
    list = new int[maxSize];          // Line 5
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)  // Line 6
      list[i] = otherList.list[i];    // Line 7
  }
  return *this;  // Line 8
}
```

The biggest issue that is making this hard to understand is the fact that in the definition of the function, it returns `*this`. Is `*this` a `const` object? I don't think it is so why are we allowed to return a non-`const` object when the return type is supposed to be `const`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the body of a non-static member function, the expression `this` can be used to get a pointer to the object the function has been called on [[expr.prim.this]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.this). Since your `operator =` is not a const member function, `this` will point to a non-const object (which makes sense since we're assigning a new value to something). Thus, `*this` will result in a non-const lvalue of type `cAssignmentOprOverload`. However, a reference to const can be bound to a non-const lvalue [[dcl.init.ref]/5.1.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.ref#5.1.1). In general, a less const qualified type can always be implicitly converted to a more const qualified one. Which makes sense: you *should* be able to use a modifiable object in places where a non-modifiable one is sufficient. Nothing really that can go wrong by treating a modifiable object as non-modifiable. All that happens is that you lose the information that that object was actually modifiable. Just the opposite, treating a non-modifiable object as modifiable, is problematic…

Note that this way of writing an overloaded `operator =` is not [how this is typically done](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations). The canonical form would be

```cpp
cAssignmentOprOverload& operator=(const cAssignmentOprOverload& otherList)
```

i.e., returning a reference to non-const…

Answer (score 0):

From [implicit_conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

- A prvalue of type pointer to cv-qualified type T can be converted to a prvalue pointer to a more cv-qualified same type T (in other words, constness and volatility can be added).

Comment: That quote applies only to *pointers*. OP is binding a non-`const` lvalue to a `const` lvalue reference, which is not a qualification conversion. See other answer above.

Comment: Agree, this is reference initialization.